# How to get rows exactly like they are displayed in react mui datagrid? (filtered and sorted in the same way?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Im making selected row move up and down on arrow clicks and for that I need to get rows from mui datagrid preferably using useGridApiRef hook. It's crucial that rows are filtered and sorted so they match what's visible in dataagrid.

I got to the point where i can get sorted but not filtered rows.

```
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  function arrowsEventListener(event) {
    if (event.key === "ArrowUp" || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
      const sortedData = apiRef.current.getSortedRows();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [functions intended for row exporting](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#customizing-the-rows-to-export). Here's a minimal example:

```
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

// if you just need the ids
const filteredSortedIds = gridFilteredSortedRowIdsSelector(apiRef);

// if you also need the row models
const filteredSortedRowsAndIds = gridFilteredSortedRowEntriesSelector(apiRef);
```